# Reg Ex to Allow Minimum Two Digit Numbers and Max Can be anysize

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to validate(JavaScript) the comma separated string of integers. It should allow minimum two digits numbers and there should not be any limit on the max size.

```
function allowonlyTwoDigitIntegers(field) {
        if (/^[0-9]{2,10}$/.test(+field))
            return true;
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I am using the following function, but it is not working. I don't understand the problem here...

Example: `1,22` : Gives InValid
          `11,22` : Gives Valid
          `11,9999999999999999999999999999999999999` etc : Gives Invalid (This should be Valid)

I converted the Comma separated string to array and in Loop I am calling this above function by passing each individual value.

Conditions Need to Satisfy : 
1. Single digits should not be allowed.

Comment: What's the format of comma separated string ?

Comment: Please show us some data, with both passing and failing cases.

Comment: could you show me an example ?

Comment: Updated with Example

Comment: What's the rule here to place comma `,` ? Is the format `two digits` `,` `any number of digits` ?

Comment: It could be any digits, any digit .....But min size should be Two Digits...single digit should not be allowed

Comment: replace , with . and check if the figure is >=10. So 

`field.replace(",",".")>=10;`

this will fail though with 9,9999999999999999 (16 or more nines after the comma)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say what "not working" means. You have limited the maximum to 10, so not really consistent with "*…not be any limit on the max size*".

`/^\d\d+$/` should do the trick.

```js
function checkValue(value) {
  document.getElementById('result').textContent = /^\d\d+$/.test(value);
}
```

```html
<input onblur="checkValue(this.value)">
<span id="result"></span>
```

You also say "*…the comma separated string of integers…*" so do you want to check each integer between commas, or remove all commas and test what's left? If you want the former, consider:

```js
function checkValue(value) {
  return /^\d\d+$/.test(value);
}

function checkNumbers(s) {
  return s.split(',').every(function(v){return checkValue(v)});
}

var testSet1 = '12,1231,12,312312';
var testSet2 = '12,1231,1,312312';

[testSet1, testSet2].forEach(function(set) {
  document.write('<br>set : ' + set + ' pass? : ' + checkNumbers(set));
});
```

#### Edit

If you just want to test the entire string, then:

```
/^(\d\d+)(,\d\d+)*$/
```

will do, e.g.

```js
['123,232,44,21','12','1','1231,123123123123,1231','123,2'].forEach(function(s) {
  document.write('<br>' + s + ': ' + /^(\d\d+)(,\d\d+)*$/.test(s));
});
```

Comment: op wants to check for comma separated string of integers where each num having a min of two digits.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Perhaps not that OP wants, then how come some of the examples he mentioned worked at least...reason is what RobG mentioned...

Comment: I am checking the single values between commas, It should not be a single digit. ....I tried the above one..it is failing for Single digits....

Comment: Sorry some mistake from my side...it is working RobG

Answer (score 0):

using a pattern that describes the whole record (all the fields at the same time):

```
function allowonlyTwoDigitIntegers(record) {
    return /^\d{2,}(?:,\d{2,})*$/.test(record);
}
```

or using its negation:

```
function allowonlyTwoDigitIntegers(record) {
    return !/\b\d\b|\B,|[^\d,]|^$/.test(record);
}
```